# Why would a file rename fail in java

Tags: java

I have the following snippet of java code:

```
File directoryToMoveTo = new File(file.getParent()+"_TEMP");
boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(directoryToMoveTo,file.getName()));
if (!success){
    logger.warn("Failed to move [%s] to temp Directory.");
}
```

file is passed in as an argument to the method and is one of an array of files obtained like this:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        logger.debug(String.format("Testing file [%s]",name));
        boolean passed = name.endsWith(getFileDescription().getFilePattern());
        logger.debug(String.format("Passed [%s]",passed));
        return passed;
    }
});
```

Why would success by false in the first snippet?

I tried this code in isolation on a different file and it seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obvious situations:

- the target file already exists
- the target directory doesn't exist
- the target directory is on a different file system
- the target directory is read-only (or at least, the current user doesn't have write access)

I'd *expect* those to at least potentially fail (the JavaDoc explicitly says that a lot of this behaviour is OS-dependent) - have you tried them?

Comment: John Skeet can do anything :) Thanks Jon that was indeed the issue... I added a check for the directory existing and a mkdir if it wasn't there.

Comment: @Stroboskop: You can perform edits for the first few minutes of an answer's life.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to debug such issues in native java methods?

Comment: @gaurav: What exactly do you mean by "native" here? Functions called by JNI, or built-in Java code? I'm really not sure what sort of situation you're asking about - it's probably best for you to ask a new question with a lot more detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet WinNTFileSystem class has a native method called rename0(); It  returns false and I want to know why it returns false?

Comment: @gaurav: As I said, I suggest you ask a new question with more detail. (For example, it's not clear whether you mean "whenever it returns false I want to know more detail" or "I have a specific situation and I don't know what's going on." But don't add a comment here explaining that - ask a new question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure Jon. I will ask a new question with details.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. It was because the directory I was copying to didn't exist.

surrounding with this if statement worked:

```
if (directoryToMoveTo.exists() || directoryToMoveTo.mkdir()){ }
```

Comment: how to debug such issues in native java methods?

Answer (score 1):

Original doesn't exist?
Already a file at the destination path?
Destinatination path doesn't exist?
Source file read only?

Just a few ideas

Answer (score 1):

I can think of:

- target directory does not exist
- not enough access rights (target directory write protected)
- not enough free space on target directory's data partition
- ...

Answer (score 1):

The file may be still open, even though you closed it: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6266377

Answer (score 0):

Not to forget you might not be allowed to write/change/rename a file.
Hardly ever a problem in windows, but common in Unix environments.

Answer (score 0):

To find the exact reason why it is not working you could `System.out.println` these paths and try to move them from OS level. That would give the good indication why is it not working.

Comment: how to debug such issues in native java methods?